# Microsoft Flow to add event to outlook calander

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I am trying to create a flow to create an event in outlook calendar but facing some issues when I add the `date time field` value to `Start Time field`.

So I used formula to format Date time as

> formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['StartDate'],'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')

[image]

Also tried convert to utc formula but still getting error as

> convertToUtc(formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['StartDate'],'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'), 'India Standard Time')

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Your formula for date time like this:**

```
1. formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/Start Time'])
2. formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/End Time'])
```

**Flow input:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati